# UnitTest Jest for dispatch Action in Redux

Tags: redux, jestjs

I'm new to unittesting Redux with Jest.

I have the following Action:

```
export const stepDone = (step) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: STEP_DONE, payload: step});
}
```

How can I test this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
//Mock the dispatch function with jest's built in mocking functions
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
//Call the action
stepDone(999)(mockDispatch)
//Check it was called with the correct argument
expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({type: STEP_DONE, payload: 999})
```

The magic of Redux is that when you're testing actions and reducers you're generally just testing pure Javascript so it's not particularly complicated.

Comment: Thank Watson for answer ^^. I found this resolution :)